# Ensuring UI updates are on the UI thread

Tags: c#, async-await

Consider:

```
async Task FooAsync()
{
    await BarAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    UpdateUI(); // Bug
}
```

I'm looking for a way to systematically ensure this doesn't happen.

Perhaps a naming convention, where methods that must be run on the UI thread get a special suffix. Or static checking, where an [UIThreadOnlyAttribute] on a method means that any caller must have that same attribute, and may not call `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

As long as your application is layered reasonably, it shouldn't be an issue.

UI layer (e.g., event handlers) and the logical UI layer (e.g., ViewModel) require a UI context and should not use `ConfigureAwait`. Other layers should use `ConfigureAwait`. That's a simple guideline that has worked well for me.

Answer (score 2):

As a sanity check, at the beginning of the `UpdateUI` method you can manually verify whether the current thread has the proper synchronization context. For a WinForms app, it could look like this:

```
void UpdateUI()
{
    Debug.Assert(SynchronizationContext.Current is WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext);
    // ... 
    // Do the actual UI update
}
```

For a WPF app, the first line would be:

```
Debug.Assert(SynchronizationContext.Current is DispatcherSynchronizationContext);
```

That works for me.

Comment: What's the point of that? UI code usually already throws an exception when accessed from the wrong thread.

Comment: @svick, usually it does, but not always at the beginning, especially if it updates the `ViewModel` first.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to do this with compile-time code injection, such as PostSharp. I have never done anything like this, but the documentation seems to indicate you could come up with a creative solution. Link to [Custom Architecture Constraints](http://doc.postsharp.net/##custom-constraints) with PostSharp.